# Build 2D Array of Canvas RGB values

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, multidimensional-array, rgb

I'm trying to send a 2D array of RGB values to PHP from the array of values from the getImageData().data method:

```
for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4){

    // If you want to know the values of the pixel
    var r = imgData.data[i + 0];
    var g = imgData.data[i + 1];
    var b = imgData.data[i + 2];
    var a = imgData.data[i + 3];

    //[...] do what you want with these values
}
```

From this, how would I create a 2D array of RGB values of an entire canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var rgb = [];
for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4){

    // If you want to know the values of the pixel
    var r = imgData.data[i + 0];
    var g = imgData.data[i + 1];
    var b = imgData.data[i + 2];
    var a = imgData.data[i + 3];

    var x = Math.floor((i/4) % imageData.width);  
    var y = Math.floor((i/4) / imageData.width);
    rgb[x] ? (rgb[x][y] = [r,b,g,a]) : (rgb[x] = [[r,b,g,a]]);
}
```

Comment: Quick Question: since I don't think I need the Alpha value for what I'm doing, should I just drop "a"? :)

Comment: Hm, for some reason not all of the pixels  are being grabbed. Some of the objects in the second array are null, as I found when I ran it through `JSON.stringify()`. :O

Comment: how about now, I ran it through a 10x10 image and it produce the right  (x,y)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again mate. :-D Have a good evening (or day, depending on your time zone). x)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but if your concern is transferring the image data (not necessarily building an array on the client side), `toDataURL()` might be an even simpler way to transfer your image data...

The HTML5 `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` method will produce a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for your image data - i.e. a really long, text-encoded version of the PNG.  No need to grab the image data manually.  Likewise, you could use a JPEG encoding if that's preferable.

If you send this string to the server, PHP can decoded back to binary form *directly* by passing it as the first argument to [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (i.e. `$binary = file_get_contents($dataURL)`).  You can then save this to disk or do whatever you want with the binary PNG data as you would with a file you had just loaded off disk.

Comment: I know about toDataURL(). Unfortunately - and perhaps I should've mentioned this in the question- the browser this is for doesn't support the function. :-( But thanks. :)