# Create Image From 2D RGB Array

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, multidimensional-array, rgb

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291992/build-2d-array-of-canvas-rgb-values), I managed to get a 2-dimensional array (in JavaScript) of rgb values from a canvas' imagedata. Now that I have it, is there a way to use PHP to reconstruct the canvas image from the 2D RGB array?
Specifically, how do I get the 2D JS array into PHP (JSON I believe, but I don't know how) and then how do I use it to remake the image? :-)

Edit:

I forgot to mention that the browser lacks `toDataURL()`, which is why I'm trying this method.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to convert the canvas imagedata to a data URL using the `canvas.toDataURL()` method. You will get a string that you can easily transfer using a standard POST request.

PHP then has `base64_decode()` to convert the data URL back into an image stream.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the browser this is intended for lacks `toDataURL()` :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should do it as @devnull69 says, but if you absolutely must build the image on the serverside with PHP, use [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), [imagecolorallocate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) and [imagesetpixel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php).

Comment: The browser this is needed for unfortunately lacks `toDataURL()`. :-(

How would I use those functions to reconstruct the 2d array? Sorry, I've never done anything like this before.

Comment: I'd like to be able to get the base64 data of the created image as well. Curse the browser's lack of `toDataURL()`...

Comment: Check the linked php docs pages linked for some example code.